# Is there a shorter way to write this XSLT match?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, libxml2

I have an XSLT 1.0 match like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@title | /ns:Library/ns:Book/@author | /ns:Library/ns:Book/@isbn | /ns:Library/ns:Book/@publisher"/>
```

Is there a shorter way to write this?

I would hope for something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[title|author|isbn|publisher]"/>
```

But obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to write what you have attempted is:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[name() = 'title' or name() = 'author' or name() = 'isbn' or name() = 'publisher']"/>
```

which is of course not really considerably shorter. But there are other ways to write code that is more concise:

**1 Write separate templates for the element and attribute matches**

To avoid overly long expressions you could split your code into separate templates. In a first template, match the element:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then, write a template for attributes:

```
<xsl:template match="@title|@author|@isbn|@publisher">
   <!--Process attributes-->
</xsl:template>
```

**2 Specify which attributes should *not* be matched**

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[name() != 'date']"/>
```

Ultimately, it depends on your input XML data and the XSLT context whether any of those methods makes sense. For example, if there are, say, 100 attributes that you don't want to match, then the second idea is not helpful.

Your main focus should be first on accuracy (producing the correct output XML), second on readability of code. If changes to your XSLT code do not improve either of those, then perhaps it's a bad idea to change the stylesheet at all.

Comment: @nwellnhof You're right - thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is very much context driven. Without seeing how (from which context) this template is being applied, (and without seeing the XML and the rest of the stylesheet), any answer is pretty much a guess. Technically, you could write:

```
<xsl:template match="@title|@author|@isbn|@publisher"/>
```

and apply this template from the context of `/ns:Library/ns:Book`.

---

Keep in mind that XSLT is naturally verbose and brevity is rarely a top priority.

Comment: +1, There is a superfluous `]` at the end of the match. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you can write

```
match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/(@title | @author)"
```

In 1.0 a possible option is

```
match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[name()='author' or name()='title']"
```

but I prefer the verbose original. In Saxon at least (I can't speak for other processors) a pattern that matches explicit names will always be much faster than one that matches a wildcard (* or @*) and relies on predicates.

Are you sure you really need the `"/ns:Library/ns:Book/"` part? Are you sure that `match="@title|@author"` wouldn't do the job?

Comment: I do need the context, since the attributes in question appear all over the original XML file, yet I need to apply the "override" to just a single node. (This is a contrived example based on a more complex one.)

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of being shorter with XSLT 1.0 I'd often write something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[contains('title|author|isbn|publisher',name())]"/>
```

Or using a global variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="attrNames">title|author|isbn|publisher</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[contains($attrNames,name())]"/>
```

**Edit**

As @nwellnhof mentioned this would also include attributes that match only parts of the string like `it`, `auth`, `sb`, `pub` etc, so this makes only sense if those cases are known to not be present.

---

In XSLT 2.0 my prefered solution would be:

```
<xsl:variable name="attrNames" select="'title','author','isbn','publisher'"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns:Library/ns:Book/@*[name() = $attrNames]"/>
```

Comment: This would include attributes like `it`, `auth`, `sb`, `pub`.

Comment: @nwellnhof yes of course, you would have to know your xml structure to some point to be sure no other attributes are included.